# Maximum of list subject to condition

Tags: prolog

I have a list as follows `[[_,A,D,_,_],...]`. I want to find the maximum `A` subject to `D` being equal to some value. I have written the following code, but it does not work. Can anyone help?

```
maxL([[_,Max,C,_,_]],C,Max).   
maxL([[_,A,D,_,_]|F],C,Max):- 
    D==C, maxL(F,C,B), Max is max(A,B).
maxL([[_,_,D,_,_]|F],C,Max):- 
    D>C, maxL(F,C,B), B is Max.
maxL([[_,_,D,_,_]|F],C,Max):- 
    D<C, maxL(F,C,B), B is Max.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using library aggregate, it's easy

```
maxL(L, C, Max) :- aggregate_all(max(A), member([_,A,C,_,_], L), Max).
```

test:

```
1 ?- maxL([[_,1,y,_,_],[_,2,y,_,_],[_,3,n,_,_]], y, M).
M = 2.
```